# Change uib-tabset content based on ng-table row click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tabs, ngtable

I'm new to Angularjs, and web programming period, but I've made some progress on this.

So, I have an ng-table and I have ng-click working so that it changes the color of the row that is selected, but I also want the content of a tab to change based on the same click.

What I have so far:

**index.html**

```
<style>
    .selected {
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered ">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index, user.information)">
          <td data-title="'First Name'">{{user.firstName}}</td>
              <td data-title="'Last Name'">{{user.lastName}}</td>
          </tr>
    </table>


    <uib-tabset type="pills">
      <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
                heading="{{tab.name}}"
                active=tab.active>
                {{tab.content}}

      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

**myStuff.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngTable'])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {
        $scope.names = [{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "information": "Alpha"},
                                        { "firstName": "Mary", "lastName": "Manson", "information": "Bravo"}, 
                                        {"firstName": "Bob", "lastName": "Smith", "information": "Charlie"}];

        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({ 
                count: 20 
            }, {
            data: $scope.names
        });

        $scope.setClickedRow = function(index, information){
            $scope.selectedRow = index;
          $scope.information = information;

          //now I want to set the tab content to the value of information, my first guess was this below, that doesn't work.
          //$scope.tabs.content = $scope.information;
    }

    $scope.tabs = [{id: 1, name: "heading", active:true, content: "no user selected."},
                   {id: 2, name: "heading2", active:false, content: "static content"}];

    });
```

So, if you look at the `setClickedRow` function I have comments where I think this should go, as well as one of the things I tried, but I can't seem to get all the way there.

The goal is to just have the `heading` tab, which has the id or 1, to have whatever information is set to in the `names` array.  So, for example, if the user selected the Mary Manson row, I would expect the `heading` tab to contain the content of "Alpha".

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kcjLnk8/), but I didn't actually get the tabset working in it b/c I'm new to jsfiddle too....but maybe it will help to show it.

Comment: You need to know which tab to set the content of.  Then you can set the content of that tab.

Comment: I always want it to go into the tab named ```heading```.  My bad, I thought I explained that in the question, but it's really not clear.  I'll rephrase that.  Even knowing that though, I'm still not sure how to define that in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index of the tab you need to set the content of, you can use `$scope.tabs[someIndex].content = $scope.information;`.

If not, but you know a property of the tab (like the name) you can use [.filter()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) like this: `$scope.tabs.filter(function(t){ return t.name == 'heading'; })[0].content = $scope.information;`

If you can pass the tab in as a parameter to your method (which in this case it doesn't look like you can, but for reference) you can simply say `tab.content = $scope.information;`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for both examples.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand the question but I observed that your `ng-controller` element is not wrapping the `<uib-tabset>` element. So the `<uib-tabset>` element doesn't even have the scope of the controller from which you are trying to pass the `tabs`. Try doing this. Might just solve your issue at least partially.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered ">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index, user.information)">
          <td data-title="'First Name'">{{user.firstName}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Last Name'">{{user.lastName}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <uib-tabset type="pills">
      <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
        heading="{{tab.name}}"
        active=tab.active>
        {{tab.content}}
      </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code.  I think that was just a typo as I was typing it into jsfiddle, which is where I copy/pasted it from.  Good catch though, I would have hated to have confused someone looking for this later.